# Stretching part of an image from a sprite sheet across a div using only css

Tags: html, css, sprite

I have a div that is 1x5 and takes an embeded image from a sprite sheet. I want to either repeat or expand this div over the area of a larger div. Is there a css-only way to do this? Or would it require javascript?

Comment: It's a little unclear what it is you are trying to do. You are trying to use one div as an **overlay** of another div? If so, assuming the divs are related, this is possible using positioning but I'm not sure how the sprite is relevant. We need a demo (or at least HTML and some CSS) to understand your requirements.

Comment: Not sure there's a way of doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CSS transform to expand it out

```
<style>
    #outerDiv {
        height: 320px;
        width: 800px;
    }
    #innerDiv {
        height: 32px;
        width: 160px;
        background-image: url('images/mysprite.png');
        background-position: 32px 64px;

        transform-origin: top left;
        transform: scale(5, 10);
    }
</style>
```

for the HTML

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="innerDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Just adjust the scale according to your needs.